# alternative to page-break-inside:avoid because of compatibility issues

Tags: css, printing, cross-browser

I have a php file with 's and the things in the div should stay on one page,
for this possebillity i found this:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_print_pagebi.asp

However like you can see its only compatible with opera and nothing more.
I dont want to demand my users to use opera so I was wondering if there was a alternative to the "page-break-inside:avoid".

Thanks
Matthy

Answer (score 3):

Support for print specific CSS is pretty crappy.  Have a look at [the CSS discuss Wiki](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=PrintStylesheets) for an extensive guide (it also has a link to a browser support compatibility table).  I have had some success with `page-break-before: always` when I was playing around with this sort of thing a few weeks back - as long as your div is less than a page long you may be able to just force a page break before it?

Comment: I've had *some* success with that, too.  You'll have a lot of issues with page breaks, though.  I spent almost a day working on it, and I eventually had to just move on.  We ultimately resorted to using blank divs with page-break-before and hoping things worked out ok...(cringe)