# Printing a html page - page breaking

Tags: css, printing, printing-web-page

I have a page which has a bunch of `divs` one after the other, generated by a loop, all having the same class, and all the `divs` contain images and text. I need to style this page for printing. I have followed all basic principles relating to size, color, margins and the likes.

However, I don't want the boxes to split between pages when they are printed, as it happens when a box begins near the end of a page and some text is printed and the rest on the next page. I used javascript to insert a page-break div (has the style `page-break-before:always`) when the total height of the divs on the page exceeds `800 (assumed value).`

However when I print, text size changes and the divs get longer/shorter and page breaks are misplaced.

I am doing the same thing that the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104622/alternative-for-page-break-inside-avoid) says. My question is what do I assume the width/height of the printed page as? Or is there a better solution?

How do I deal with this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** : I use print-specific css, fyi.
Also I have specific media styles and print styles.

EDIT (attempt to visualize)

```
-------div 1------ 
 |                 |
 |                 |
 |                 |
  -----div 2-----
 |                 |         WRONG
 |                 |
 |                 |
  ----div 3-------
 |                 |
 |                 |
 |  auto page break|
 ----page 1 ends---- 
 |                 |
 |                 |
 |                 |
 ----div 4----------


 -------div 1------ 
 |                 |
 |                 |
 |                 |
  -----div 2-----
 |                 |         RIGHT
 |                 |
 |   script 
    generated 
     page break    |
  ----div 3-------
 |                 |
 |                 |
 |                 |
 ----page 1 ends---- 
 |                 |
 |                 |
 |                 |
 ----div 4----------
```

Comment: Let's get this clear, you want the page-break to occur between <div>s but not inside them? But you don't want a page-break if there is enough space for another <div> ?

Comment: Make sure that the assumed height is correct in print page. Is it really 800? More? Less?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104622/alternative-for-page-break-inside-avoid

Comment: @ibrahim,

The problem is not the assumed height. I have the same font size 12 pt in both the media and print. But on screen it shows up differently and on paper it shows up differently. As a result what on screen is 800 pixels appears to be bigger on paper.

Comment: @ibrahim that is what i am doing right now..But the heights get distorted between screen and print

Comment: @ryan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2751/discussion-between-ibrahim-ashshohail-and-ryan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I assumed the width as 600 and my height as 800. I haven't found the best combination but this works as well.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using CSS defined for print:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

If your CSS has the `media` attribute set to `screen` or something other than `print` or `all`, the printer will not see your CSS.

Comment: I am. That's why the difference shows up. I compute page-breaks using javascript and the print css distorts the heights.