# Print html div without breaking its contents between two pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i use window.print() to print my web page, the result will be several pages. I have some html div elements that must not be break between two pages. Although, because the page contents are dynamically created, i have no way to know when my div will be broken or not.

Is there any css or javascript i can use to tell that a specific div must not be broken between two pages?

I saw the css rule "page-break-before" that i could use surrounding my div but that will cause  a page break even in cases that it could be avoided (increasing the total print pages unnecessarily).

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907680/css-printing-avoiding-cut-in-half-divs-between-pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is this (but has compatibility issues)

```
.noBreak { page-break-inside: avoid;  }
```

Current compatibility ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/page-break-inside)):

```
Chrome     Firefox (Gecko)    Internet Explorer    Opera     Safari (WebKit)
1.0        19.0 (19)          8.0                  7.0       1.3 (312)
```

Other SO Discussion: [alternative to page-break-inside:avoid because of compatibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246636/alternative-to-page-break-insideavoid-because-of-compatibility-issues)

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp)

Answer (score 0):

it is necesary to connect another css for print:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="PATH_TO_CSS" />
```

and write styles just for print.

Comment: How does this answer his question?