# Page-break-inside not working in firefox

Tags: html, css

I need to generate a bunch of tables each with a header(`<thead>` made out of two `<tr>`). The tables than need to be printed. A single table should not break inside unless it's too long for one page, the header should than get repeated. Header should never be split onto two pages. I have noticed that `page-break-inside: avoid` does not work in Firefox < 19. Is there any workaround for it? As for now my tables and my headers break whenever they want.

Comment: The page-break-inside property is only supported by Opera. [http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp)

Comment: I know that but is there any workaround for it to work in other browsers?

Comment: The short answer is no, not with HTML/CSS alone, at least. You could consider generating a PDF for a higher degree of control.

Comment: was just about to type what @matthewpavkov wrote.

Comment: Personally, I would use the `page-break-inside` and for those with older browsers, they'll just simply be out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDN says that Firefox 19 is the earliest version to support the `page-break-inside` property.  Looks like you're out of luck.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/page-break-inside

Maybe you can find something useful from this question:  [alternative to page-break-inside:avoid because of compatibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246636/alternative-to-page-break-insideavoid-because-of-compatibility-issues)